# Merge rows into one row - Orcale 11g Database

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have this SQL Statement here:

```
SELECT DATETIME, DWH_ACCOMODATIONS.NAME, SUM(NIGHTS) 
FROM dwh_data JOIN DWH_ACCOMODATIONS ON dwh_data.fk_accomodation = DWH_ACCOMODATIONS.CODE 
WHERE dwh_data.fk_accomodation = 998 AND DATETIME BETWEEN 201001 AND 201012
GROUP BY DWH_ACCOMODATIONS.NAME, DATETIME, NIGHTS;
```

This statement gives me this result:

```
DATETIME         NAME             SUM(NIGHTS)
--------------   --------------   --------------   
201011           Hotel 1<998>     12689
201012           Hotel 1<998>     18495
201012           Hotel 1<998>     4958
201012           Hotel 1<998>     37580
201011           Hotel 1<998>     85938
201011           Hotel 1<998>     27488
201011           Hotel 1<998>     9874
```

The problem as you can see is that datetime and one hotel name are duplicate in the table

Now I'd like to get a result like this:

```
DATETIME         NAME             SUM(NIGHTS)
--------------   --------------   --------------   
201011           Hotel 1<998>     1268949
201012           Hotel 1<998>     1869859
```

For sure the nights should also be summed up.

I already tried it with this in the GROUP BY:

```
GROUP BY ROLLUP(DWH_ACCOMODATIONS.NAME), ROLLUP(DATETIME), ROLLUP(NIGHTS)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GROUP BY` is wrong; you should remove `NIGHTS` from it.

```
  SELECT DATETIME, DWH_ACCOMODATIONS.NAME, SUM (NIGHTS) sum_nights
    FROM dwh_data
         JOIN DWH_ACCOMODATIONS
            ON dwh_data.fk_accomodation = DWH_ACCOMODATIONS.CODE
   WHERE     dwh_data.fk_accomodation = 998
         AND DATETIME BETWEEN 201001 AND 201012
GROUP BY DWH_ACCOMODATIONS.NAME, DATETIME
```

---

If you want to "merge" `datetime` values, then use `listagg` function:

```
  SELECT LISTAGG (datetime, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY datetime)
            AS datetimes,
         dwh_accomodations.name,
         SUM (nights)
            sum_nights
    FROM dwh_data
         JOIN dwh_accomodations
            ON dwh_data.fk_accomodation = dwh_accomodations.code
   WHERE     dwh_data.fk_accomodation = 998
         AND datetime BETWEEN 201001 AND 201012
GROUP BY dwh_accomodations.name
```

Comment: Yeah thanks, but how do I have to change the statement to use the ROLLUP or CUBE in the GROUP BY

Comment: Why do you think you need ROLLUP or CUBE? The way you described the problem, all you have to do is - as I said - remove NIGHTS from the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: And is it also possible to merge the datetime rows into one row and use the first for numbers as the row value

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you meant to say.

Comment: I would like to merge the rows from the Datetime column into one row

Comment: That would be LISTAGG, then. See edited answer, please.